# Computer turns off while playing 3D games

Tags: troubleshooting, power

About a week ago, my computer started to randomly turn off while I was playing 3D games. I initially suspected temperature issues. I have SpeedFan installed, idle PC temp is 99C and running a game about 120C. I opened the case to clean the filter/CPU heatsink/fan blades, aerosol dusted, and ensured that all fans were working properly and cable connections were snug. When the issue persisted my next suspicion was temporary voltage drops (I live on the top floor of older 2 family house, bad wiring is probable). I have bought an UPS, charged the battery overnight and hooked everything up. Now, when I turn on my PC the UPS alarm kicks on for a few seconds as soon as the Windows desktop appears. When I run a game, as soon as I get past the menus to actual 3D content, the UPS alarm kicks on and after about 30 seconds the PC turns off. What does this mean exactly? Troubleshooting tips?

**Relevant specs:**

- 700W Rosewill PSU
- GIGABYTE GA-X58A-UD3R
- GeForce GTX 470 (550W PSU minimum)
- Intel Core i7 3Ghz quad core CPU
- Cooler Master Hyper 212 CPU heatsink

Comment: Have you made sure all your firmware is up to date, on your motherboard as well as your video card?

Comment: Where is that temperature data from? CPU? GPU? MB? Inside Chassis just somewhere? And how is the temperature now?

Comment: ever tried to update display card? You may require the latest [nVidia Drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us)

Comment: Vid card is up-to-date. Will check firmware for mobo. PC temps are from the SpeedFan software.

Answer (score 2):

i'm going to blame the power supply.

The UPS is likely warning you about excessive current draw.

i can't imagine that the UPS is not able to handle a regular computer - so i'm going to blame the power supply for drawing too much (short?)

Comment: PSU was my next suspect, I did cheap out a bit with the Rosewill. Will order something beefier and higher end and report back.

Comment: reporting back, installed a brand new Corsair PSU, same result.

Comment: Then it's time to start replacing everything :(